# Unity Android build crashes with JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x200001 (index 0 in a table of size 0)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

After building an Android app with Unity I noticed that on a specific device it would crash. After looking in the logs I found the following line:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x200001 (index 0 in a table of size 0)
```

This was the issue that caused the app to crash and prompt the user with a window saying "Unfortunately, [App Name] has crashed".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my issue was quite weird. The device's time was set dramatically wrong (7 years in the past). After setting the correct time on the device the issue was solved.